# How to made test "fail" if browser direct to a wrong URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to check a link, for example I clicking a link and then browser open a different page (lets say click on "About Us" and you get directed to "about us" page). I have to verify that I navigate to the right page with a right URL. My question is how to made a test fail (not just print url in the console) if instead of "About Us" page browser direct me to home page.
Any recommendations? I am using webdriver with java.

Comment: Check if you get a `302` at any point.

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

WebDriver will allow you to obtain the URL from the browser, which you can then use in an assertion.  Something like `AssertEqual(expectedUrl, driver.getCurrentUrl());`